# Android + Volley: how to set image icons into ImageView during the loading process?

Tags: android, callback, android-imageview, android-volley

I have the following method which should read given URL with image and return image as the bitmap. I implemented into method Volley feature which should display progress or error icon in the given `ImageView` during the Request.

```
/**
 * Processing Image request and gets the image with given URL
 */
public Bitmap makeImageRequest(String url, ImageView imageView) {
    //TODO: resolve issue with BitmapLruCache
    ImageLoader il = new ImageLoader(queue, new LruBitmapCache());
    il.get(url, ImageLoader.getImageListener(
            imageView, R.drawable.ic_media_play, R.drawable.ic_media_pause)), new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
            if(response.getBitmap() != null) {
                mBitmap = processImageResponse(response);
                Logger.i("Image successfully loaded");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Logger.e("Image cannot be loaded");
            Logger.e(error.getMessage());
            VolleyLog.d(Constants.Global.ERROR, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            mBitmap = null;
        }
    });
    return mBitmap;
}
```

The problem is that Android studio is throwing an error at the end of the `ImageListener` method. The error says that:

```
});

; is expected
```

What should I do to update the method to get working it properly?

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

*-- I rewrote this answer --*

The `ImageLoader.get` accepts two arguments: `requestUrl` (a `String` object) and `listener` (an `ImageLoader.ImageListener` object).

I think you should remove `ImageLoader.getImageListener(imageView, R.drawable.ic_media_play, R.drawable.ic_media_pause)),` from the code.

```
il.get(url, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
        if(response.getBitmap() != null) {
            mBitmap = processImageResponse(response);
            Logger.i("Image successfully loaded");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Logger.e("Image cannot be loaded");
        Logger.e(error.getMessage());
        VolleyLog.d(Constants.Global.ERROR, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        mBitmap = null;
    }
});
```

Or if you want using default `ImageListener` implementation, delete `ImageLoader.ImageListener` instantiation. You can specify loading icon and error icon with this default `ImageListener`.

```
il.get(url, ImageLoader.getImageListener(imageView, R.drawable.ic_media_play, R.drawable.ic_media_pause));
```

Comment: After the removing clocing bracket i got error:
Cannot resolve method get


Error:(94, 11) error: no suitable method found for get(String,ImageListener,<anonymous ImageListener>)
method ImageLoader.get(String,ImageListener,int,int,ScaleType) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method ImageLoader.get(String,ImageListener,int,int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method ImageLoader.get(String,ImageListener) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Comment: @redrom I rewrote my answer.

Comment: Yes, this update is working, but how can i set state icon?

Comment: @redrom Added an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is an unnecessary char ")" in

```
 ImageLoader.getImageListener(
        imageView, R.drawable.ic_media_play, R.drawable.ic_media_pause))
```

Please try:

```
    /**
 * Processing Image request and gets the image with given URL
 */
public Bitmap makeImageRequest(String url, ImageView imageView) {
    //TODO: resolve issue with BitmapLruCache
    ImageLoader il = new ImageLoader(queue, new LruBitmapCache());
    il.get(url, ImageLoader.getImageListener(
            imageView, R.drawable.ic_media_play, R.drawable.ic_media_pause), new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
            if(response.getBitmap() != null) {
                mBitmap = processImageResponse(response);
                Logger.i("Image successfully loaded");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Logger.e("Image cannot be loaded");
            Logger.e(error.getMessage());
            VolleyLog.d(Constants.Global.ERROR, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            mBitmap = null;
        }
    });
    return mBitmap;
}
```

Comment: Not working, it seems that params are not applicable to get method.